# Why the ouput display the first line of the data in .txt?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, oop

Why the data only print for the second line only? Supposedly it will print all the data by columns right? Which line I made a mistake on this java programming?

**What I've done and won't work:**

- Put for(int i=0; i < cols.length; i++);
- Put  while (sc.hasNextLine())

Above information that i stated is both give me
this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at Forensic.main(Forensic.java:28)
```

---

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Forensic 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            File fin = new File("Bill.txt");                                            
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fin);
            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    
            File foutBelow = new File("BelowAmount.txt");
            FileWriter writerBelow = new FileWriter(foutBelow);
            PrintWriter printBelow = new PrintWriter(writerBelow);
    
            printBelow.println("Payment less than or equal to RM 1000");
            printBelow.println("Record\t\tUser ID\t\t\tPayment");
    
            String string = ""; 
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(bufReader);
            while((string = bufReader.readLine()) != null)
            {   
                string = scan.nextLine();
                String cols[] = string.split(","); 
    
                printBelow.println(cols[0] + "\t\t\t" + cols[1] + "\t\t\t\t" + cols[2]);
            }
            System.out.println("Data successfully transfered");
    
            bufReader.close();
            printBelow.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfE)
        { 
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        catch (IOException ioE)                                           
        { 
            ioE.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> in Bill.txt file

```
1208,236,289.90
1209,221,299.70
1210,236,479.60
1211,236,200.00
1212,221,560.60
1213,289,4000.00
1214,289,235.60
1215,236,280.50
1216,221,100.20
1217,221,2800.30
1218,236,1400.70
1219,289,778.90
1220,289,778.90
1221,236,420.50
1222,277,235.60
1223,277,229.90
1224,236,479.60
1225,221,300.20
1226,289,1400.70
1227,236,479.60
```

> Output of BelowAmount.txt

```
Payment less than or equal to RM 1000
Record      User ID         Payment
1209            221             299.70
```

The output is above. Display directly second row of the data.

Comment: I believe it goes like this: `while(scan.hasNextLine()) {`. You don't need the BurfferedReader either: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(fin);`

Comment: Actually, I'd say the scanner is unnecessary, since only whole lines are read, and a buffered reader can do that.

Comment: @DevilsHnd : i did that. then ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException appeared

Comment: @RealSkeptic : whenever i remove scanner, this _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
 at Forensic.main(Forensic.java:28)_ appeared

Comment: @ShazwaniRashid that's not because of the scanner. It's because you have a line with no commas, and you don't check first that your array has at least 3 elements. It seems the first line in your text file is empty.

Comment: @RealSkeptic : may you show me which line? Not clear what you say

Comment: @kleopatra i put the screenshot at the link below the code

Comment: repeating: don't show screenshots (or otherwise created images) of plain text - they are useless in multiple respects, here f.i. they can't to copied to reproduce the problem. That said: you have competing readers - the scanner and the bufferedReader. Drop one or the other as already suggested in the very first comment by @DevilsHnd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, there are many ways to read a file, format its contents and write the formatted contents to another file but you seem to be mixing them all together.

The below code shows one way, which uses class `java.util.Scanner`.
(Notes after the code.)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Forensic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path source = Paths.get("Bill.txt");
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(source);
             PrintWriter printBelow = new PrintWriter("BelowAmount.txt")) {
            printBelow.println("Payment less than or equal to RM 1000");
            printBelow.println("Record\t\tUser ID\t\t\tPayment");
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String string = scan.nextLine();
                String[] cols = string.split(",");
                if (cols.length == 3) {
                    printBelow.printf("%s\t\t\t%s\t\t\t\t%s%n", cols[0], cols[1], cols[2]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't assume that the contents of the file you are reading is as you expect it to be. Hence, in the above code, after calling method `split`, I check to make sure that the line read from the file has the expected format.

Refer to [Scanning and Formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanfor.html) in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Refer to the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/index.html) to see how to create and use classes like `java.io.PrintWriter`, for example. It has a constructor that takes a string argument. Hence no need to create a `File` and then a `FileWriter` in order to create a `PrintWriter`.

I also advise using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that you close all the files you use in your program.